# Does TypeScript's duck-typing exclude class constructors?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a type (`PickFromConstructor`) that is able to extend a constructor and has the ability to have a class's static optional properties omitted. Can anyone tell me what properties are missing from the type `A` that are in the type `PickedA` and furthermore explain what causes the further differing when the `InstanceType<...>` of a constructor type has additional properties of its own? Can you also explain how the assignments at the bottom of the file do not error? The handbook is quite light on information when it comes to type extension.

```
class A {
  constructor(argumentA: string) {
    return;
  }

  static staticPropertyA: string = "a";

  static staticMethodA() {
    return;
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(public propertyB: string) {
    return;
  }
}

class C {
  constructor() {
    return;
  }

  methodC() {
    return;
  }
}

interface IConstructor<T> {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

interface IClassConstructor<T extends IConstructor<any>> {
  new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>): InstanceType<T>;
}

// both versions have the same effect on the `...Extends...` types
// type PickFromConstructor<T extends IConstructor<any>, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, K> & IClassConstructor<T>;
type PickFromConstructor<T extends IConstructor<any>, K extends keyof T> = Pick<
  T,
  K
> &
  (new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => InstanceType<T>);

type PickedA = PickFromConstructor<typeof A, keyof typeof A>;
type PickedB = PickFromConstructor<typeof B, keyof typeof B>;
type PickedC = PickFromConstructor<typeof C, keyof typeof C>;

type AExtends = A extends PickedA ? true : false; // false
type ExtendsA = PickedA extends A ? true : false; // true

type BExtends = B extends PickedB ? true : false; // false
type ExtendsB = PickedB extends B ? true : false; // false

type CExtends = C extends PickedC ? true : false; // false
type ExtendsC = PickedC extends C ? true : false; // false

const a: PickedA = A; // no error
const pickedA: typeof A = a; // no error, but will produce error if PickFromConstructor uses `(abstract new (...) => ...)`

console.log(a, pickedA);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EsF22bMwHK59CZvEcPpt-vo-mtqel6FllODRx95rgOoTE-HFtgZ29re7Jt8iRTEsHw+ho9n0HiU9NM9bE-iC6QXdTvY66-9m-Lx13bQPiaFx4tbTP56XsAAoobUTA1jwEqcbLr28AAPxCoQWxsOsIAQPQkjQAK0DwYhX4in+4bwDeK7Af+KqQdBBCwWhYAIUhKGCmk9DyF28TYaB1iJCBAFgau0BQbR0BwRRiHIah6F0V2TEAWuHGsYRCRcSRZHCYJgrCfRS5tGJKrWB0bEqpeUyyTxfGUYp5GUZhWzqW6-YSlesbsR03EwbxJkCdRzl0TEmLQGAbC6bhcDGZg6AIngOh4B5qQFNZ-hsLuflgAFQUGKFOrZAQODQNcnAgCABQ6L4RBbElpDQJwFoDoGI6wtABCITAAAGFDZBwGzpYWJL3HWFzFrwdXyF06AgPQ9wgOgVAUDquhRbAHZIEAA)

I would expect all of the six `...Extends...` types at the bottom of the file to be `true` but this is evidently not the case.

Comment: Ah, okay, now I got it. You are basically `type BExtends = B extends Constructor<B> & Omit<typeof B, never> ? true : false;`, of cource that won't work, you need the `typeof B` there, not the `B = InstanceOf<typeof B>`

Comment: Is this just a typo? You seem to understand that `typeof A` because that's what you use to make `PickedA`, but then your 6 `Extends` types all compare instance types to constructor types.  Once you fix those typos do you still have an issue?

Comment: Ah, of course, sorry. The six examples above are all `true` when I fix that. I am struggling to create an abstracted example of the code I'm using that isn't working. I should probably note that the classes are much more complex in my project but I am not sure what feature of their complexity causes the problem. I'll re-ask the question if I can figure out how to show the problem.

In the project, doing `PickFromConstructor<typeof Class, any> extends typeof Class ? true : false` is `false` whereas the inverse condition is`true`. Very confounding.